# Drupal 6 & PHP: how to crop part of string with php

Tags: php, string

I'm a newbie php guy.

I have 1 string output from Drupal's date module as below;

> Dec 5 2010 (All day) - Dec 7 2010 (All
>   day)

and I need to display only date, without (All day).

So, how can I display it as below? is there any php func that I can crop some parts of string?

> Dec 5 2010 - Dec 7 2010

appreciate helps!! thanks a lot!

Comment: this has nothing to do with drupal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$in_string = 'Dec 5 2010 (All day) - Dec 7 2010 (All day)';
$out_string = str_replace('(All day) ', '', $in_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stripped = str_replace(' (All day)', '', 'Dec 5 2010 (All day) - Dec 7 2010 (All day)');
```